# Facebook url-debugger: Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I get this error on some articles **Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address.**

I think that this problem has arisen in recent times..

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug in facebook or if the fault is on our website.

Comment: I also get this error: **Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped**. I have also asked the hosting company if there is something wrong with the DNS, but it seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of your website which is facing this issue?

Comment: Examples:  [example 1](http://www.jmini.se/nyheter/31464/anna-malm-n-foll-for-huskvarna-ff)
[example 2](http://www.jmini.se/nyheter/31465/agne-bengtsson-tillforordnad-klubbdirektor-i-hv71)
If you "Fetch new scrape information" in the url-debugger they will be  ok. But there is an error in the existing scrape.

Comment: Seeing this too - intermittent and hard to debug.  One article which had this problem was [this one](http://spright.com/healthy-eating/peanut-butter-and-jelly-cupcakes/).  'Fetch new scrape information' fixed it.  @f_karlsson are you on AWS by any chance?  We are using Route 53 DNS with an ELB alias record.  Not sure if that is related.

Comment: The site is on a Windows VPS in Sweden

Comment: It seems to be working now but i'd like to know what the problem was anyway..

Comment: In case it helps, I got this error when I didn't include 'http://' or 'https://' in the url - it needed the full url to work for me, not just from www.